# How to instantiate angular service with multiple resources?

Tags: angularjs, service, instantiation, meanjs

I have an angular service based on meanjs for rents. Originally it looked like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('rents.services')
    .factory('RentsService', RentsService);

  RentsService.$inject = ['$resource', '$log'];

  function RentsService($resource, $log) {

    var Rent = $resource(
      '/api/rents/:rentId',
      {
        rentId: '@_id'
      },
      {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        },
        getByCarId:
        {
          method: 'POST',
          params: {
            rentId: 'bycar'
          },
          isArray: true,
          hasBody: true,
          requestType: 'json',
          responseType: 'json'
        }
      }
    );

    angular.extend(Rent.prototype, {
      createOrUpdate: function () {
        var rent = this;
        return createOrUpdate(rent);
      }
    });

    return Rent;

    // and all other function that are the same as down below
}());
```

Then I added a second resource

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('rents.services')
    .factory('RentsService', RentsService);

  RentsService.$inject = ['$resource', '$log'];

  function RentsService($resource, $log) {

    var Rent =
      {
        basic: $resource(
          '/api/rents/:rentId',
          {
            rentId: '@_id'
          },
          {
            update: {
              method: 'PUT'
            },
            getByCarId:
            {
              method: 'POST',
              params: {
                rentId: 'bycar'
              },
              isArray: true,
              hasBody: true,
              requestType: 'json',
              responseType: 'json'
            }
          }
        ),
        carUsageStats: $resource(
          '/api/rents/car_usage'
        )
      };

    angular.extend(Rent.basic.prototype, {
      createOrUpdate: function () {
        var rent = this;
        return createOrUpdate(rent);
      }
    });

    return Rent;

    function createOrUpdate(rent) {
      if (rent._id) {
        return rent.$update(onSuccess, onError);
      } else {
        return rent.$save(onSuccess, onError);
      }

      // Handle successful response
      function onSuccess(rent) {
        // Any required internal processing from inside the service, goes here.
      }

      // Handle error response
      function onError(errorResponse) {
        var error = errorResponse.data;
        // Handle error internally
        handleError(error);
      }
    }

    function handleError(error) {
      // Log error
      $log.error(error);
    }
  }
}());
```

Until I added second resource, this resolve function for creating new rent worked fine

```
  newRent.$inject = ['RentsService'];

  function newRent(RentsService) {
    return new RentsService();
  }
```

But when I added second resource (and had to address the one I want by using property name - cant use Rent.query() but Rent.basic.query()) instantiating new Rent no longer works. I added console log outputs around and code stops executing at line var rent = new RentsService(). Querying works fine. What is the correct way of making new object using service with multiple resources?

Comment: It doesn't work because RentsService isn't a constructor. It will work like new RentsService.basic(). At this point naming works against you, because constructor functions should have PascalCase names. Would make more sense if it were new rentsService.Basic(). Btw, merging multiple resources under same namespace is bad, they are tightly coupled. They should be different services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to get it working following your example. I named the service with capital first letter because the example service in meanjs was also named this way. I will change it and constructor name as you advised. I put two resources into same service because I thought if they deal with the same mongoose model they belong together. I will make a separate service then.